# Intermediate class beetwen interface and main Form class to access textbox

Tags: c#

Is there an option to do intermediate class like this:

> INterfaceClass -> IndirectClass <- FormClass
>
> ____________________|^|_______________
>
> ```
>                 AnotherClass
> ```

And I want to use object from FormClass (textBox) in AnotherClass, where IndirectClass will be responsible for deliver me acces to that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a reference to your form class when constructing an instance of the indirect class.

```
public class IndirectClass
{
    private FormClass _form;

    public IndirectClass(FormClass form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    public FormClass
    {
        get { return _form; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
var f = new FormClass();
var c = new IndirectClass(f);
c.f.[whatever]; // Note that [whatever] needs to be visible outside of f
```

You can also store a variable to a `FormClass` member inside `IndirectClass` itself to get rid of one level of indirection.

Comment: I used reference and property to get my textbox. Stupid am I... I didn't get it earlier.

Comment: I would definitely not do this....you should create an interface that exposes the text box property and have that interface be injected into your indirect class.